# Best way to handle a database with lots of dynamically added columns?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using a python script to run hourly scrapes of a website that publishes the most popular hashtags for a social media platform. They're to be stored in a database (MYSQL), with each row being a hashtag and then a column for each hour that it appears in the top 20, where the number of uses within that past hour is listed. 
So, the amount of rows as well as columns will constantly increase, as new hashtags appear and ones that have previously appeared resurface into the top 20.
Is there a best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is poorly suited for a relational database such as MySQL.  The best way to go about it is to either redesign your storage layout to a form that a relational database works well with (eg. make each row  a (hashtag, hour) pair), or use something other than a relational database to store it.